What is the difference between a noun modifier of a verb in its base form or participle form?
For example, what difference does it make if I name the CPU core that does the checking work "check/checking core"?

Neither is not all that clear without context explaining what "the checking work" is, but checking is somewhat better because it inidicates an ongoing activity. I would assume that "a checking core" checks. But it could be the case that in CPU design, it has been given the name "the check core".  So "better" would depend on whether you're trying to express what it does or want to use a standard name, if one exists.

In English grammar, choosing the right verb tense is essential. But you're not using a verb - you're using a compound noun that contains a verb, like a "carving knife" (a kind of knife for carving meat) or a "spinning top" (an old-fashioned toy for children). These are recognised nouns, and to change the tense of the verb contained within it would result in the noun sounding wrong at best or not being recognised at all at worst.
Not all computing terminology is everyday language so I wouldn't like to say what is right or wrong, but if there is a proper name for a CPU core that does checking you should find out what it is and use that term.
However, if you are creating your own term to describe a single CPU core doing checking because you have assigned it that process, I would say that "checking core" best describes a core that checks things. I base this on the fact that a "checksum" in computing is not a sum that checks, but rather a sum that can be used for checking. Outside of computing, a checkpoint is a point at which something is measured or checked, not a point that checks things.
